# .Net webservice API, multiple calls same time, getting duplicate inserts in SQL instead update

Tags: sql, .net, api, insert, duplicates

I have a .net API which will execute the Steoredproecure and Insert in the SQL table or update few columns. In API this runs in transaction.

RecordID is the primary key filed in this table but Customer and Date fields are the unique combination and should not have duplicate records instead update if it already has a record with that combination.

We get almost 6 to 7 thousand records daily to insert. Sometimes API is calling the SP twice almost with a millisecond difference. I have a check in SP as below,

```
SELECT  @RecordExist = Count(*) 
    FROM    Records (nolock) 
    WHERE   ServiceDate =   @Date
    AND     CustomerAccount     =   @CustomerAccount
```

If the record count is more than 0 then I am updating it, otherwise insert. Starting to end it is in transaction.

Somehow when request comes multiple times at same time (this is expected from application whenever user updates the record and there is an automatic update with 5 minutes interval) the above SP check is not able to find the records and going to insert again instead of update the record.

Any solution from database to stop this duplicate? Or from API to hold until the check has been done and then sent to update?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too concerned about the update sequence then a SQL MERGE will solve your problem.

the Merge will automatically either insert or update.

Merge on Cust & Date - 
When Matched - Update
When Not Matched by Target Insert

Should do the trick.